# Excel Sheet Not Showing when trying export gridview data to excel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to export Gridview Data to Excel. I searched a lot and got the code to export to excel. But excel not showing. When using **Response.End()** a threadexception comes so i used **HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()** instead of Response.End()

Please help me find out a Solution.

```
Response.Clear();

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=FileName.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();

System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

gridSalary.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
// Response.End(); 

HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is a working example

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=file-name.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
    }
```

**Note** : There is a function `VerifyRenderingInServerForm` which is overridden. And i guess you missed it.